# Docker: make custom docker image with parameter

Tags: postgresql, docker, dockerfile

I am trying to create alpine postgreSql docker image to learn creating docker image so i crated dockerfile:

```
FROM alpine:latest

MAINTAINER groot

ENV LANG en_US.utf8

ENV DBNAME hoge_db

ENV USERNAME name

RUN apk update && apk upgrade && \
    apk add --no-cache postgresql postgresql-contrib  openrc && \
    /etc/init.d/postgresql start && rc-update add postgresql && \
    /etc/init.d/postgresql start && \
    psql -U postgres -c "CREATE DATABASE $DBNAME WITH ENCODING 'UTF8' OWNER=$USERNAME;"

VOLUME /var/lib/postgresql/data
ENTRYPOINT ["psql", "-U", "postgres"]
EXPOSE 5432
```

In creating postgre database command i want to **Database Name** and **User Name** gave by user, so i added `ENV DBNAME hoge_db and ENV USERNAME name` is it right ? How can user replace this var with own database name and user when creating container?

Comment: he will probably use `-e` option when performing `docker container run` command to set/override environment variables. However your database will be created when image is build so the same database is always present at the container startup.

Comment: There's a long section discussing [`ARG`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#arg) in the official Dockerfile documentation.

Comment: I think i made mistake because i want to create database and user when user want's create container not when i am creating image so in think i need create database in CMD section ! is right?@michalk

Answer (score 0):

Build arguments can be used to provide build time values to the image.

```
FROM alpine:latest

MAINTAINER groot

ENV LANG en_US.utf8

ARG DBNAME=hoge_db
ENV DBNAME ${DBNAME}

ARG USERNAME=name
ENV USERNAME ${USERNAME}

RUN apk update && apk upgrade && \
    apk add --no-cache postgresql postgresql-contrib  openrc && \
    /etc/init.d/postgresql start && rc-update add postgresql && \
    /etc/init.d/postgresql start && \
    psql -U postgres -c "CREATE DATABASE $DBNAME WITH ENCODING 'UTF8' OWNER=$USERNAME;"

VOLUME /var/lib/postgresql/data
ENTRYPOINT ["psql", "-U", "postgres"]
EXPOSE 5432
```

and then override the necessary arguments:

```
docker build --build-arg DBNAME=testdb --builg-arg USERNAME=root .
```

Comment: He runs the `psql` command on image build so the same database will exist in every container from this image. So even overriding environment variables will not help.

Comment: But the $DBNAME variable in the create database statement will be overridden by the `--build-arg` right? @michalk

Comment: Yes but still he will have to rebuild the image each time he wants to change the DB and USERNAME. Better approach would be to make entrypoint script which will start postgres and add the user and db. And then this script will be using env variables. right now creating the db should not be the part of Dockerfile `RUN`.

Comment: both `ARG  and ENV ` together are necessary?@MaartenDev

Comment: yes to ensure the value is persisted to the environment at run-time @sayreskabir